# Oracle SQL Developer history with wrong dates of execution

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.0.13 (in French) and use the SQL History pane which is sometimes useful to retrieve unsaved queries and/or after a crash of the application (which happens quite a lot by the way).

One big problem though, the dates of execution - which I mostly use when looking for an old query are completely wrong.

[image: View of my SQL History pane]

As you can see :

1. Dates (in an apparent `dd/mm/yy` format) are way in the future sometimes
2. The tooltip above the selected date seems to give the exact date (in `m/d/y` format)

I believe it is about date formatting and maybe the SQLHistory file in C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\SQL Developer\SqlHistory.xml, but I can't find any way to set this up.

Anyone has a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in 4.0.13. From [the forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/11318508#11318508):

> In SQL Developer Version 4.0.0.13 , the Timestamp is showing incorrectly in the SQL History window
>
> SQL for today -  03-JAN-14  is showing with a timestamp of 01-MAR-14
>   Looks like the day and month have been reversed when formatting.

... with response form Jeff Smith:

> All kinds of fun bugs there - they've been addressed for our next patch/release and the developer also tells me, if anything, the product should be faster and more responsive in that area.

It works as expected in 4.0.1.14, so I can only suggest you upgrade to the current version. There are probably a lot of other bugs squashed now too; it might even crash less often...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought I was up to date in terms of software version, but it seems I'm a little behind. Thanks again +1